# Objects rotation in 3D space - Ray tracing

Tags: c, 3d, rotation, raytracing, rotational-matrices

I’m working on a ray tracing project in C. I have troubles to handle the rotations of objects. All the intersections are done in the world space, and I don’t want to use an object space.

For the Square (not a cube) I have a center position in the world space, a 3D normalised orientation vector and his side length. I’ve already created a ray-square intersection function which verify if the ray hits the square using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769430/find-corners-of-rectangle-given-plane-equation-height-and-width) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685433/ray-square-intersection-3d).

The rotation is done on the orientation vector depending on which key the user press en the keyboard (1 of the 3 axes is chosen here). The rotation works for the x and y axis when the square is in the same direction of the axis chosen to rotate. But it doesn’t work when I start rotating on two different axis at the same time.

Here is my ray-square intersection function:

```
int     test_hit_square(t_ray ray, t_square *square, t_hit *hit)
{
    t_plane         plane;
    t_hit           tmp_hit;
    int             ret;
    t_vec           up;
    t_vec           right;
    float           half_size;
    t_vec           C1;
    t_vec           C2;
    t_vec           C3;
    t_vec           C4;
    float           X;
    float           Y;
    t_vec           p;
    t_vec           normal;

    normal = get_normalised(square->dir);
    plane.origin = square->origin;
    plane.dir = normal;
    ret = test_hit_plane(ray, &plane, &tmp_hit);
    if (ret == 0)
        return (0);
    up = (fabs(square->dir.z) > 0.7) ? (t_vec){0, 1, 0} : (t_vec){0, 0, 1};
    right = vec_cross(up, normal);
    normalize(&right);
    up = vec_cross(normal, right);
    normalize(&up);
    half_size = square->size / 2;
    C1 = add_vec(square->origin, add_vec(mul_vec(right, half_size), mul_vec(up, half_size)));
    C2 = add_vec(square->origin, sub_vec(mul_vec(right, half_size), mul_vec(up, half_size)));
    C4 = sub_vec(square->origin, add_vec(mul_vec(right, half_size), mul_vec(up, half_size)));
    C3 = sub_vec(square->origin, sub_vec(mul_vec(right, half_size), mul_vec(up, half_size)));
    p = add_vec(ray.origin, mul_vec(ray.dir, tmp_hit.t));
    X = vec_dot(sub_vec(p, C1), sub_vec(C2, C1)) / get_norm_2(sub_vec(C2, C1));
    Y = vec_dot(sub_vec(p, C1), sub_vec(C3, C1)) / get_norm_2(sub_vec(C3, C1));
    if (X >= 0 && X <= 1 && Y >= 0 && Y <= 1)
    {
        hit->t = tmp_hit.t;
        hit->normal = check_normal(ray, normal);
        hit->square = square;
        return (1);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Here are the rotations functions:

```
t_vec      x_rotation(t_vec vec, float alpha)
{
    t_vec  res;
    res.x = vec.x;
    res.y = vec.y * cos(alpha) - vec.z * sin(alpha);
    res.z = vec.y * sin(alpha) + vec.z * cos(alpha);
    return (res);
}

t_vec      y_rotation(t_vec vec, float alpha)
{
    t_vec  res;
    res.x = vec.z * sin(alpha) + vec.x * cos(alpha);
    res.y = vec.y;
    res.z = vec.z * cos(alpha) - vec.x * sin(alpha);
    return (res);
}

t_vec      z_rotation(t_vec vec, float alpha)
{
    t_vec  res;
    res.x = vec.x * cos(alpha) - vec.y * sin(alpha);
    res.y = vec.x * sin(alpha) + vec.y * cos(alpha);
    res.z = vec.z;
    return (res);
}
```

[Rotation error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRhFB.gif)

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.  Have you tried debugging your code, this might highlight the issue, Antoine.

Comment: Before it is reasonable to even look at this question a [mcve] is needed.  i.e. if I want to put this into my compiler,  compile will not occur without definitions for `t_ray`,  `t_square`, etc.

Comment: ... and part of a [mre] would be to explain how the actual behavior differs from the expected behavior.  That is not obvious from the animation you provided.

Comment: Sounds like you might be encountering [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).  Consider using _quaternions_ instead